# .htaccess - universal rule

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

this is my first question on this site. Sorry for any mistakes and etc. I have tried to search for a similar topic, but i didn't found anything.

Example:
.htaccess file (just a little part of):

```
# Rules for admin meniu 
RewriteRule ^adm/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)?/?([a-zA-Z0-9]+)?/?$ index.php?page=adm&page_id=$1&id=$2&act=$3 [NC,L]
```

This one rule fits few subcategories of admin panel. As we can see I have 1 static and 2 optional variables. The static one is for switch($_GET[page_id]) on my admin.php. Second variable (optional) is for some id (News, Users, Projects or smth..). Third variable (also optional) is for action (delete, edit, ban and so on..). So, if I want to check user's information i am using this link:

```
index.php?page=adm&page_id=[users_page]&id=[users_id]
```

and I don't need the action. But if i want to check some news:

```
index.php?page=adm&page_id=[news_page]&id=[users_id]&act=[edit]
```

But sometimes i just need to get to subcategory:

```
index.php?page=adm&page_id=[news_page]
```

And finally...

Question:
Is this a good idea to make this rewrite rule universal for couple of admin panel's categories or I should do this separately for each one. Or there is some other solutions? Keeping in mind that some parts of that link is not using. Sometimes I don't need &act=... or sometimes I just need only &page_id=... And there are a lot of situations like this one. Hope u will understand this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not keep it clean and simple and have 3 separate rules to handle various cases:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^adm/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=adm&page_id=$1&id=$2&act=$3 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^adm/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$ index.php?page=adm&page_id=$1&id=$2 [NC,L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^adm/([a-z]+)/?$ index.php?page=adm&page_id=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Well.. This my question is a little bit silly, but i wanted to be sure and do things in a right way. Yes, this method is clean and simple. Just wanted to find out what others are thinking about this. I am quite starter with .htaccess and mod_rewrite so just wanted to listen for more advanced people what are they thinking. Thanks for your answer! :)

Comment: After answering thousands of questions on these rewrite question do you seriously believe I will suggest something which is not the best practice? I can easily combine 3 rules into one but that won't be easily readable and maintainable rule for future enhancements.

Comment: No no no, don't get me wrong. I have no doubt about yours skills. I appreciate Your answer! Just explained why I have asked this. :) Thanks again! ;)

Comment: Sure no worries. As I said I can submit an answer that will be just 3-in-1 rule, if that's what you're looking for.

Comment: Nah, this is good enough. Just wanted to be sure that longer way isn't very newbie move and impractical solution.